# Postgres role security for multi-tenant database

Tags: postgresql, security, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant application where the Postgres DB schemas are set up as follows:

- `_admin` (tables that are invisible in the UI to standard users but need to be read-accessible, common across all tenants)
- `_master` (table defs only, no keys or other constraints)

  - `customer` (columns...) `CHECK false NO INHERIT`
  - `etc` (columns...) `CHECK false NO INHERIT`
- `acme` (primary tenant-specific schema for tenant "acme")

  - `customer INHERITS _master.customer`
- `acme_oms` (order mgmt schema for tenant "acme")

  - `etc INHERITS _master.etc`
- `acme_xx` (where xx is another schema for tenant "acme")
- `widgets_inc` (primary tenant-specific)
- `widgets_inc_oms` (etc)

The `_master` schema contains all table definitions that will be inherited in the tenant-specific schemas. This works well. I can place `CHECK false NO INHERIT` on all these table definitions to ensure that nothing is ever inserted into them.

I'd like to set up the roles this way:

- `db_admin superuser` (has access to everything including schema
  modification and replication)
- `db_acme` (has transparent read access to `_admin`,
  read-write access to everything in all schemas starting with "acme", but no schema modification privileges, no access at all to other tenant schemas)
- `db_widgets_inc` (etc...)

Two questions:

1. What would the `CREATE ROLE` code look like for the tenant-specific users?
2. Would restricting read access to the `_master` tables still allow the tenant-specific users to access the data in their own schema tables?